# Exploding an object by parts

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, selection-tools

Hi I have imported an engine model in blender, I want to explode the complete engine part wise(PFA).there are so-many parts i cant keep moving all of them it will take lot of time. so is there any trick or option to do it quickly?
(This explode is not similar to the cube explode, here i want all the parts to be moved away)[the image shown is from different software but i want to achieve similar output from blender][https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEGDt.png]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's no officially prescribed way that I'm aware of, but this is a quick way to do it;

In these example, I have one object with a lot of loose parts that are all, themselves, manifold.

### To modify a single object with multiple meshes

Enter edit mode on the object with Tab;

[image]

Change your pivot point to "Individual Origins";

[image]

Scale the meshes down to the desired separation;

[image]

Set the pivot point back to "Median Point"

[image]

Scale the meshes back up to the desired display size;

[image]

### To use separate objects, one mesh each

[image]

I hit space (or F3, or whatever your search key is set to) and search for "Separate";

[image]

Then, I select "loose parts";

[image]

Now, search for, and select, "Set Origin"

[image]

Then select "To Geometry";

[image]

Each mesh will have it's own object. Now change your pivot point to "Individual origins";

[image]

Now, with all the objects selected, scale them down to a desired spacing;

[image]

[image]

Change your pivot point back to "Median Point", then scale up to the desired final size;

[image]

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderESmith It helped.